# Generate PDF from gsp page

Tags: pdf, grails

I am using grails 2.5.2. 
I have created a table which shows all the data from database to gsp page and now i need to save that shown data in a pdf format with a button click.What will be the best way to show them into  a PDF and save it to my directory. please Help

Comment: Take a look at the rendering plugin, https://grails.org/plugin/rendering?skipRedirect=true

Comment: there is no documentation for rendering plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got idea from itext. Used itext 2.1.7 and posted all the values to pdf from a controller method. Used images as background and paragraph and phrase to show values from database.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itext` for converting HTML into pdf using the code below:

```
public void createPdf(HttpServletResponse response, String args, String css, String pdfTitle) {
    response.setContentType("application/force-download")
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=${pdfTitle}.pdf")
    Document document = new Document()
    Rectangle one = new Rectangle(900, 600)
    document.setPageSize(one)
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream())
    document.open()
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(args.toString().getBytes())
    ByteArrayInputStream cis = new ByteArrayInputStream(css.toString().getBytes())
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, bis, cis)
    document.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though answering this question late,take a look at grails export plugin.It will be useful if you want to export your data to excel and pdf( useful only if there is no in pre-defined template to export).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there is some predefined template that i have used . So i did using itext .